# Как вывести список постов с количеством комментов под ними через Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

На самописном движке я делаю 2 запроса: один в таблицу с постами доставая 10 последних штук, второй в комменты добавляя к нему WHERE IN с десятком id вытащенных первым запросом постов. Страница генерируется за 0.06 секунды.

Теперь пробую то же самое провернуть через Eloquent в Laravel.

Сначала попробовал сделать это через акцессор в модели **Post**

```
public function getCountCommAttribute() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Comment', 'id_post')->count();
}
```

и выводить их во вьюшке через **count_comm**, но оказалось, что при таком подходе Laravel делает 10 дополнительных запросов в базу, каждый по 25 миллисекунд!

Потом решил переделать все доставая кол-во комментов сразу же в первом запросе прицепив их с помощью **withCount**.

В модели **Post** создаем отношение hasMany:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Comment', 'id_post'); 
}
```

Добавляем **withCount** к запросу:

```
$posts = \App\Models\Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                                ->where('moderate', 1)
                                ->withCount('comments')
                                ->paginate(10);
```

Все работает. Во вьюшке кол-во комментов доступно по {{post.comments_count}}. Но, движок генерирует для всего этого и делает глупейший запрос в базу, который обрабатывается 1.1 секунды!

```
select 
`post`.*, 
(select count(*) from `comments` where `post`.`id` = `comments`.`id_post`) as `comments_count` 

from `post` 
where `moderate` = 1 
order by `id` desc 
limit 10 
offset 0
```

Я что-то не понял в Eloquent и можно как-то сделать все красиво или для этого придется городить запросы вручную через DB::table?

Comment: Запрос, который Вы представили, выдаёт Laravel? Если да, то городить что-то не имеет смысла, потому что тот же самый результат будет. Тут уже от веб-сервера и СУБД зависит.

Comment: Да, это Laravel такой ужасный запрос собирает по withCount. Я через DB::table уже собрал свой запрос, который выполняется за 20 мс, и его уже передаю во вьюшку. Но как-то это все странно выглядит. Я думал, что это можно как-то экологично средствами ORM сделать.

Comment: Выглядит запрос так:
    $comments = DB::table('comments')
        ->select('id_post', DB::raw('COUNT(id_post) as count'))
        ->whereIn('id_post', $arr)
        ->groupBy('id_post')
        ->get();